# conditional proxypass ajp rules using ip whitelist

Tags: apache, conditional-statements, config, ajp, proxypass

I've successfully created a ProxyPass ajp rule which works fine, but now i want to restrict the access of certain urls using an ip-whitelist. In other words, when someone comes from an ip that is not on the whitelist the request should not be proxypassed (and, ideally, some sort of access denied should be issued)

i don't have control over the machine i'm proxy-passing to, so i can't put the ip-whitelist on that machine's configuration. That's why i'm trying to configure this on the same machine that has the proxypass rule.

Defining a <Location /path> with 'Allow from'-rules doesn't work, because the request is still proxypassed. I guess this simply means the proxypass rules preceed the location-rules.

I've tried to work around it by setting an environment variable depending on the remote-address *(because then i could proxy non-whitelist-ips to nonexistent url - not pretty, but it would achieve the goal)*, but it seems the proxypass rule doesn't work with environment variables. Something as simple as this:

```
SetEnv custom_proxypath=/
ProxyPass %{ENV:custom_proxypath} ajp://10.50.40.21:8009/
ProxyPassReverse %{ENV:custom_proxypath} ajp://10.50.40.21:8009/
```

doesn't work. while

```
ProxyPass / ajp://10.50.40.21:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://10.50.40.21:8009/
```

works perfectly.

I'm out of options. Does anyone else have a suggestion how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I learned this today.... SetEnv is applied *later* in the request cycle than the ProxyPass, so it isn't set in time. However, SetEnvIf is applied early enough, as are environment variables set with RewriteCond/RewriteRule. You should be able to refactor this to a SetEnvIf that is always true and that will do the trick.